# PowerShell - Pasting content with Get-Content line by line instead of all in one text

Tags: powershell, script, hosts

So.. I'm not quite an expert in PowerShell scripting ..
I got this script and I'm trying to add a list of websites to the hosts file to block.
I can't seem to figure out how to make it add each domain line-by-line instead of everything in one line.

I was wondering if anyone could help me or point me in the right direction.

Here's the code I have:

```
param([string]$DesiredIP = "127.0.0.1"
    ,[string]$Hostname = @(Get-Content ".\src\hosts")
    ,[bool]$CheckHostnameOnly = $false)
#Bætir við færslu í HOSTS skránna.
#Krefst -RunAsAdministrator
$hostsFilePath = "$($Env:WinDir)\system32\Drivers\etc\hosts"
$hostsFile = Get-Content $hostsFilePath

Write-Host "Verið að bæta við $desiredIP fyrir $Hostname í hosts skránna" -ForegroundColor Gray

$escapedHostname = [Regex]::Escape($Hostname)
$patternToMatch = If ($CheckHostnameOnly) { ".*\s+$escapedHostname.*" } Else { ".*$DesiredIP\s+$escapedHostname.*" }
If (($hostsFile) -match $patternToMatch)  {
    Write-Host $desiredIP.PadRight(20," ") "$Hostname - not adding; er nú þegar í hosts skránni" -ForegroundColor DarkYellow
} 
Else {
    Write-Host $desiredIP.PadRight(20," ") "$Hostname - að bæta við í hosts skránna... " -ForegroundColor Yellow
    Add-Content -Encoding UTF8  $hostsFilePath ("$DesiredIP".PadRight(20, " ") + "$Hostname")
    Write-Host " Búið!"
}

Read-Host -Prompt "Allt Klárt! Ýttu á ENTER til að loka glugganum ☺"
```

So my hosts file ends up like:

```
127.0.0.1        website.com test.com google.com pirates.net loremipsum.org filler.co.uk en.kremlin.ru test.com testing.com
```

My .\src\hosts file where I'm getting my list from looks like this:

```
website.com
test.com
google.com
pirates.net
loremipsum.org
filler.co.uk
en.kremlin.ru
test.com
testing.com
```

Apologies in advance. Comments and Strings are in my native language, not English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hosts are written on a single line because your code is not looping through them. I have added `foreach($line in $Hostname)` to the code. The loop allows to add the hosts to the file line by line.

```ps
param([string]$DesiredIP = "127.0.0.1"
    ,$Hostname = Get-Content ".\src\hosts"
    ,[bool]$CheckHostnameOnly = $false)
#Bætir við færslu í HOSTS skránna.
#Krefst -RunAsAdministrator
$hostsFilePath = "$($Env:WinDir)\system32\Drivers\etc\hosts"
$hostsFile = Get-Content $hostsFilePath 

foreach($line in $Hostname) {
Write-Host "Adding $desiredIP for $line in the hosts file" -ForegroundColor Gray

$escapedHostname = [Regex]::Escape($line)
$patternToMatch = If ($CheckHostnameOnly) { ".*\s+$escapedHostname.*" } Else { ".*$DesiredIP\s+$escapedHostname.*" }
If (($hostsFile) -match $patternToMatch)  {
    Write-Host $desiredIP.PadRight(20," ") "$line - not adding; is already in the hosts directory" -ForegroundColor DarkYellow
} else {
    Write-Host $desiredIP.PadRight(20," ") "$line - adding to the hosts file..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
    Add-Content -Encoding UTF8  $hostsFilePath ("$DesiredIP".PadRight(20, " ") + "$line")
}

}
    Write-Host " Done!"


Read-Host -Prompt "All Done! Press ENTER to close the window ☺"
```

**Note:** I had to translate the outputs in English to understand what was going on and kept them in my code above. You need to change them back to your language.

Comment: This works. But I'm getting a lot of errors `Add-Content : Stream was not readable.
At J:\Write-Host Script\src\Script\Test Script.ps1:18 char:5`
Every other line it adds is not readable. Any idea why?

I have a very large file to filter adult content. (About 31,000+ Domains)

Comment: Does this path `J:\Write-Host Script\src\Script\Test Script.ps1` exist on your machine? Pretty sure it doesn't. The destination folder is wrong. Note: I have put the original paths just in case you did not change them when you copied/pasted them.

Comment: It does exist. I even checked my hosts file and it adds everything that doesn't show the error in.
I ran it again. And I don't get that error anymore. Now I'm just getting error saying its being used by another process once in a while. I added  `Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1` in the loop and it doesn't show the error anymore. Could it be that the loop is too fast?

Comment: If it exists, then the error could be caused by a number of issues. Possible cause(s) and solution(s): 1) https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2209512-add-content-stream-was-not-readable   2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27370389/add-content-produces-stream-not-readable